# SQL to find next 5 most lengthy films in each category whose length is greater than the avg of length in their respective category?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, join, correlated-subquery

From the sakila database available [here](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/sakila-db.tar.gz), I want to find next 5 lengthiest movies in each category. I made this problem.
Using the query

```
SELECT fl.title, fl.length, ct.name
FROM film fl JOIN film_category fc ON fl.film_id=fc.film_id
             JOIN category ct ON ct.category_id=fc.category_id
WHERE fl.length > (SELECT AVG(fl.length) 
                   FROM film fl JOIN film_category fc ON fl.film_id = fc.film_id
                   JOIN category cat ON cat.category_id=fc.category_id
                   WHERE cat.name=ct.name);
```

I can find all the Films whose length is greater than the average of film in their respective categories. When I add `LIMIT 5`, then only 5 rows that are retrieved - I need to get 5 from each category. Adding `GROUP BY ct.name` only gives 16 rows - one from each category.

1. What query would get this done ?
2. Would it be possible to achieve this without using any correlated subquery ?
3. What can help me identify if result of correlated subquery be achieved by joining tables ?

I think it is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526219/mysql-limit-in-a-correllated-subquery), but I couldn't figure out a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody wants to download and setup your database. Provide database schema or even better sqlfiddle.

Comment: You are on the right track. 1. Write query for getting top 5 lengthiest movies for one category (use limit 5 in that query); 2. wrap it in an outer query for all categories; 3. add a check in inner query that category is equal to outer category. Ofcourse, this is a general guide thinking of a normalized db, and you should not expect a complete answer.

Comment: this might help u...`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778702/mysql-returning-x-number-of-each-group-by/18778927#18778927`

Comment: The database I picked for practice is provided by MySQL, and I having problems creating sqlfidlle, its too large. Creating a subset of the data and will get back here. Sorry, I wasn't aware of sqlfiddle yet.

Comment: SQLFiddle,[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef270b/3) is partial database schema - with only 20 titles. Have used `MIN` instead of `AVG` to get more rows, I think that won't change the solution much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has been tested (successfully) against the Sakila database...

```
SELECT title,
       length,
       categoryName
FROM ( SELECT CASE
                  WHEN film_category.category_id = @currentCategory THEN
                      @currentRecord := @currentRecord + 1
                  ELSE
                      @currentRecord := 1 AND
                      @currentCategory := film_category.category_id
              END AS recordNumber,
              film.title AS title,
              film.length AS length,
              categoryName AS categoryName
       FROM film
       JOIN film_category ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id
       JOIN ( SELECT film_category.category_id AS category_id,
                     category.name AS categoryName,
                     AVG( film.length ) AS categoryAvgLength
              FROM film
              JOIN film_category ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id
              JOIN category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
              GROUP BY film_category.category_id,
                       category.name
            ) AS categoryAvgLengthFinder ON film_category.category_id = categoryAvgLengthFinder.category_id,
            (
                SELECT @currentCategory := 0 AS currentCategory
            ) AS currentValuesInitialiser
       WHERE film.length > categoryAvgLength
       ORDER BY film_category.category_id,
                film.length
     ) AS allLarger
WHERE recordNumber <= 5;
```

This statement starts by using the following subquery to form a "table" consisting of each `category`'s unique identifier `category_id`, the `name` of the `category` and the corresponding average `Film` `length`...

```
SELECT film_category.category_id AS category_id,
       category.name AS categoryName,
       AVG( film.length ) AS categoryAvgLength
FROM film
JOIN film_category ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id
JOIN category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
GROUP BY film_category.category_id,
       category.name
```

This subquery's results are then joined to `film` and `film_catgory`.  As the subquery retrieves all the details from `category` that we will need for the rest of the statement, no `JOIN` with `category` is needed.

The resulting dataset is then cross-joined with `SELECT @currentCategory := 0 AS currentCategory` to initialise the variable `@currentCategory` within the same statement.  This does come at the cost of appending a field called `currentCategory` to the dataset generated above, so you may prefer to use the following code instead...

```
SET @currentCategory := 0;
SELECT title,
       length,
       categoryName
FROM ( SELECT CASE
                  WHEN film_category.category_id = @currentCategory THEN
                      @currentRecord := @currentRecord + 1
                  ELSE
                      @currentRecord := 1 AND
                      @currentCategory := film_category.category_id
              END AS recordNumber,
              film.title AS title,
              film.length AS length,
              categoryName AS categoryName
       FROM film
       JOIN film_category ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id
       JOIN ( SELECT film_category.category_id AS category_id,
                     category.name AS categoryName,
                     AVG( film.length ) AS categoryAvgLength
              FROM film
              JOIN film_category ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id
              JOIN category ON category.category_id = film_category.category_id
              GROUP BY film_category.category_id,
                       category.name
            ) AS categoryAvgLengthFinder ON film_category.category_id = categoryAvgLengthFinder.category_id
       WHERE film.length > categoryAvgLength
       ORDER BY film_category.category_id,
                film.length
     ) AS allLarger
WHERE recordNumber <= 5;
```

Once the `JOIN`'s are performed (and `@currentCategory` is initialised), the resulting dataset is refined to just those records whose value of `film.length' is greater than the corresponding average for that category.  The refined dataset is then sorted (not grouped) by one of the`category_id`fields (of which there will be two sharing the same value owing to the joining) and subsorted by`film.length`.

When the fields are chosen, each record's value of `category_id` is compared to the value of `@currentCategory`.  If they do not match then `@currentRecord` is initialised to `1` and `@currentCategory` is updated to the new value of `category_id`.  If they do match, then `@currentRecord` is incremented.  In either case, the value assigned to `@currentRecord` is returned to the `SELECT` statement into the field given the alias `recordNumber`.  It is thus that we are able to prepend a record number to our refined dataset.

Then all that remains is to `SELECT` all the records from the refined dataset (sans record number) where the record number is less than or equal to `5`.

Please note that the above achieve their results without the use of any correlated subqueries, instead using `JOIN`'s to tables and subqueries.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.